# bundle install failing because of activesupport

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, bundler

I've read every post I can find about this but nothing is working. I'm running a Rails 2.3.4 app and I'm trying to get bundler working so I can use Heroku as my staging server. I've installed bundler, edited the necessary files, and created the gemfile. When I run bundle install I get:

> Could not find gem 'activesupport (= 2.3.4, = 3.0.5, runtime)' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile.

Here is my gemfile:

```
source :rubygems
source :rubyforge

gem 'abstract'
gem 'actionmailer'
gem 'actionpack'
gem 'activemodel'
gem 'activerecord'
gem 'activeresource'
gem 'activesupport', '2.3.4', '3.0.5'
gem 'haml'
gem 'mail'
gem 'mime-types'
gem 'mongrel'
gem 'rails', '2.3.4'
gem 'rake'
gem 'savon', '0.7.9'
gem 'spreadsheet'
gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'sqlite3-ruby'
gem 'prawn'
gem 'mysql'
gem 'vlad'
gem 'vlad-git'
```

I've tried multiple sources and nothing works. I'm running ruby 1.8.7 with rvm.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why do you have 2 version numbers for activesupport?

Comment: I inherited this site from a previous developer, and he had both listed in his `gem list` so I included both. I'm still a novice so I put it there just in case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
gem 'activesupport', '2.3.4', '3.0.5'
```

To

```
gem 'activesupport', '2.3.4'
```

or just remove it all together, you're specifying `gem 'rails', '2.3.4'` and bundler will figure out how to get the correct version of activesupport for you as a dependency.

Comment: Thanks jdesno - I commented out activesupport and all the gems installed. Awesome, but now when I run script/server I'm getting this Bundle-related error: `$ script/server => Booting Mongrel
=> Rails 2.3.4 application starting on http://0.0.0.0:3000
/Users/bB/Sites/WBanksCDMCYP/CYP/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:105:in `const_missing': uninitialized constant Rails::Boot::Bundler (NameError)`

Comment: Unfortunately you need to do some manual setup for Bundler under rails 2.3.4. Follow the instructions here: http://gembundler.com/rails23.html if you haven't already.

Comment: Yeah I already had those changes in place, so that's not the issue.

Comment: You're using vendor/rails, are you certain it's also 2.3.4? I would recommend against using vendor/rails unless you really have to.

Comment: I just was handed the keys to this project from the previous developer, so not sure why they used vendor/rails. But the app was working fine before I tried to install bundle.

Answer (score 0):

Try bundle install, it worked for me.  The error I got was:

> Could not find activesupport-3.0.3 in any of the sources